# Set custom condition to find from Model using mongoose find()

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I just want to set some conditions in Mongoose **find()** to query from my **Routine** model. Is it possible in any way? or How to set such kind of custom conditions?

```
const List = await Routine.find({
        $where:
            () => {
                moment(currentDate).isBetween(this.startDate, this.endDate, undefined, '[]') == true &&
                    customFunc(this) == true
            }
    })
```

Where the **customFunc()** returns a boolean value

Comment: please assume that the async/await syntax is maintained properly

Comment: you can use `$lt` and `$gt`, I assume startDate and endDate are schema fields ?

Comment: Sorry for not to mention that. Yes 'startDate' and 'endDate' are schema fields @Karl L

Comment: But I am not comparing with any schema fields directly since 'currentDate' is not a schema field. So how to get that done? @Karl L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, you can do something like this. But that depends on what you store in `startDate` and `endDate` as far the date formatting is concerned

```
let curDate = new Date()
const List = await Routine.find({
                                 startDate:{"$lt":curDate},
                                 endDate:{"$gt":curDate}
                                })
```